# how to modify the interaction area of an svg text element to match its bounding box?

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

When I create text elements with Snap, say, the letter "a", the surrounding region that captures click events is far larger than the bounding box, by a scaling factor of at least 10. This means that if I create a second text element "b" that is close but visually separated from "a", the interaction regions have a large intersection, so that which element get clicked is mostly determined by which element is in an earlier/later layer.

Is it possible to shrink the interaction region to match the bounding box as closely as possible, so that layering doesn't affect which element's click event is triggered?

[Here's a jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/dromano/7todpbjf/60/), where the font size is initially set to 0.1px, which is on the order of magnitude I'm working with.  (The size of the interaction area relative to the bounding box seems to increase as font size decreases.)  Note that since "b" is created after "a", the only way to trigger "a" is clicking almost at the left edge of the canvas. What I was hoping to do is have a series of elements like these with similar spacing between them.

```js
var s = Snap("#svg");

var fontsize = 0.1;

var make_text_box = function(string, fontsize, color) {
  var text = s.text(0, 0, string);
  text.attr({
    'font-size': fontsize + 'px'
  });
  text.click(
    function() {
      text.attr({
        fill: color
      });
    }
  );

  var bbx = text.getBBox().x;
  var bby = text.getBBox().y;
  var bbw = text.getBBox().w;
  var bbh = text.getBBox().h;

  var strokewidth = fontsize / 10;
  var bbox = s.rect(bbx, bby, bbw, bbh)
    .attr({
      stroke: "black",
      strokeWidth: strokewidth,
      fill: "none"
    });

  var text_and_box = s.g(text, bbox);
  return {
    g: text_and_box,
    x: bbx,
    y: bby
  };
};

var a_box = make_text_box("a", fontsize, "red");
var b_box = make_text_box("b", fontsize, "limegreen");
b_box.g.transform("translate(" + (2 * fontsize) + ", 0)");

s.attr({
  viewBox: (a_box.x - 4 * fontsize) + ", " + (a_box.y - 4 * fontsize) + ", " + (30 * fontsize) + ", " + (10 * fontsize)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/snap.svg/0.1.0/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
<svg id="svg" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"></svg>
```

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to the question.

Comment: Sounds like you are doing something wrong, but who knows without seeing some code as Robert says.

Comment: Just added a jsfiddle example which reproduces the effect I'm describing, which seems to depend on font size.

Comment: I think that makes more sense now. Could you add the bit about the clashing fonts/texts to the fiddle as well. I have a suspicion it may need a bit of a hacky workaround. Also maybe indicate if there will be loads of different text elements, or just a few.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, Ian -- I just edited the post and jsfiddle example to incorporate them.

Comment: Ah are you using Firefox ? I don't see an issue in Chrome or Opera at all, but in Firefox the bounding area is different that displays. I'm wondering if it's a Firefox bug if so, Robert may have an idea.

Comment: Actually, there look to be issues on other versions of Chrome as well, but not the same problem eg 54.0.2840.100 (but is ok on my Chrome at home, not sure of version atm). And there do seem to be historic bugs in the area of font-sizes less than 1 and viewboxes. What about if you use a higher font-size but scale it down with a transform or something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a feeling you may need a bit of a hacky workaround for this, as I don't know of a way to do what you want. I think there's several bugs out there, or maybe it's unclear what should happen with small font-sizes. Someone like Robert may have a better idea though.

If you leave the font-size to be bigger, but then scale down the element, you may have more success. So something like...

```
var fontsize = 10;

var text = s.text(0, 0, string);

text.attr({
  'font-size': fontsize + 'px',
  'transform': 's0.05'
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7todpbjf/67/)

That's about as small as I can get it and still be able to see it and click in it. You may want to play a bit with shape-rendering and text-rendering as well to make it a bit sharper.

Comment: Thanks, Ian!  In the application I'm working on, the small font size is necessary because the view box coordinates are set earlier on, but the text should be visible at a "normal" size (like [this modification](http://jsfiddle.net/dromano/kcuosb1L/1/) of your jsfiddle), so this fix work perfectly for me.  (Although, I'd still be curious to learn if there is direct access to the size of the interaction region.)